# Can the tags "broken-links" and "dead-links" be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Similar tags:

- [broken-links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-links) ×1 -- No description
- [dead-links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead-links) ×8 -- No description